# Spring boot SOAP WS end point

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-boot, wsdl

I am producing a SOAP WS using Spring boot. I am using contract first philosophy to develop this.

I have following schema

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
            targetNamespace="www.google.com" version="1.0" 
            xmlns:tns="www.google.com" 
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="CommandRequest" type="tns:CommandRequest"/>
<xs:complexType name="CommandRequest">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="enterpriseId" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="pwd" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="command" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="CommandResponse" type="tns:CommandResponse"/>
    <xs:complexType name="CommandResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="code" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string"/>         
                </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Configuration class

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
            servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
            return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/cmd-service/*");
        }

        @Bean(name = "command")
        public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema commandSchema) {
            DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
            wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CommandServicePort");
            wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/cmd-service");
            wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("www.google.com");
            wsdl11Definition.setSchema(commandSchema);
            return wsdl11Definition;
        }

        @Bean
        public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
            return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("CommandService.xsd"));
        }   
    }
```

EndPoint code

```
@Endpoint
public class CommandEndPoint {  

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "www.google.com";
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "CommandRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<CommandResponse> command(
            @RequestPayload CommandRequest commandRequest) {
                }

}
```

The above code exposes one webservice at localhost:8090/cmd-service/command.wsdl.

I want expose two different wsdl (1.localhost:8090/service1/command.wsdl and 2. localhost:8090/service2/command.wsdl) using the same schema. Can any body suggest me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by extending MessageDispatcherServlet and seetting a enum RequestTypeStore.RequestType.

```
@EnableWs
```

@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Bean
MessageDispatcherServlet servlet() {
    return new MessageDispatcherServlet() {
        @Autowired
        private RequestTypeStore requestStore;
        public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

            HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            String URI = httpReq.getRequestURI();
            if(httpReq.getRequestURI().contains("/dns-service")) {
                requestStore.setType(RequestType.DNS_COMMAND);
            }
            else if (httpReq.getRequestURI().contains("/registry-service")) {
                requestStore.setType(RequestType.REGISTRY_COMMAND);
            }
            else {
                requestStore.setType(RequestType.UNKNOWN_COMMAND);
            }
            super.service(req, resp);

        }

    };
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = servlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/*");
}


@Bean(name = "registry-command")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema commandSchema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CommandServicePort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/registry-service");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("www.google.com");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(commandSchema);
    wsdl11Definition.setRequestSuffix("");
    return wsdl11Definition;
}

@Bean(name = "dns-command")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11DefinitionDNS(XsdSchema commandSchema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CommandServicePort2");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/dns-service");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("www.google.com");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(commandSchema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}

}
```

RequestTypeStore implementation is as below:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class RequestTypeStore {

    public enum RequestType { DNS_COMMAND,REGISTRY_COMMAND,UNKNOWN_COMMAND};
    private RequestType type;
    public RequestType getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(RequestType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
```